# How to show a large image completely on a canvas?

Tags: android, image-resizing

I want to load an image from gallery  as a bitmap an show it on a custom view(not an imageview).Here is the code for loading bitmap.

```
private Bitmap loadBitmap(String filePath, int orientation, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
            int scale = 1;
            if ((options.outWidth > width) || (options.outHeight > height)) {
                if (options.outWidth < options.outHeight) {
                    scale = Math.round((float) options.outWidth / width);
                } else {
                    scale = Math.round((float) options.outHeight/ height);
                }
            }
            options.inSampleSize = scale;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
            if (orientation > 0) {
                // rotate the image w.r.to orientation
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(orientation);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,width,height, matrix, true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            bitmap = null;
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Now my problem is that the canvas does not  show the bitmap completely.Only a part o  it.How can i adjust the image (without losing its clarity,not stretching) with screen size?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You make your view height and width to match_parent. wont that help to fit the screen?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try the ScaleType options and use the one whihc suits you the best. Follow the link below for details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: But ScaleType using with imageview.I already specified that this is a customview extending View.

Comment: You make your view height and width to match_parent. wont that help to fit the screen?

Comment: Then get you screen height and width and set you canvas size to that. Curently your canvas is bigger than screen size.